# Faulty Disk : is it possible to find faulty sectors and tell Windows to stop trying to acces it?

Tags: hard-drive

Windows is regularly complaining about a faulty disk, that I should urgently make a backup because it will soon stop from working. I got this message for over a year now, it stopped for few month and now it comes back again. Problem is that it causes blue screen on regular basis too.

Now the faulty disk in question isn't the one where windows is installed on. I wonder if it possible to find the faulty sectors and tell windows to stop from trying to access it without cutting the partition in 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it via below.

“**Task Scheduler Library**” => “**Microsoft**” => “**Windows**”. => “**DiskDiagnostic**”

Then **Click Disable**.

Fair Warning though. Although this could be false read more below.

*There is no actual way to stop the disc from trying to access faulty blocks. It will actually get worse. To the point of disc failure. 
I would backup your data fairly soon. As the disc could stop booting and you could lose potential vital data that you may have on the computer.*

Other options

**Do a ChkDsk**

Open up **CMD.exe** then type `chkdsk /f` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

That will fix any errors if there are any.

And 'chkdsk /r' will locate bad sectors and recover readable information

See if it will repair any errors.

You can also try [Eassos PartitionGuru](http://www.eassos.com/partitionguru.php) to see if it can verify and repair bad sectors.

**Note:** *Using the above method, If you find any bad sectors you need to backup before trying to repair them as the repair may remove any data close to or around the bad sectors. Also be aware if it cannot repair the bad sectors they are physical. And you need to replace the disc as soon as possible. which in this case you already have a backup. If you decide to backup before you decide to do the repairs.*

If there are errors I advise backing your data up and either waiting until it does not boot anymore or replace the disk.

Comment: Well turns out that chkdsk /f successfully repaired the disk and windows no longer complains, I'll see whether it comes back or if I still get blue screens. As for when you say I shouldn't use a faulty disk I'm not sure. I've once read a blog where it said there was a faulty disk, and once he repartitioned it to exclude the faulty sectors he used the disk for data storage and it lived 5 years going.

Comment: chkdsk by itself will not fix any errors, you need chkdsk /f or chkdsk /r. chkdsk /f does not mark bad sectors, it only fixes file system problems, chkdsk /r will find and attempt to repair bad sectors, if it cannot repair the sectors it will mark them as Bad.

Comment: It depends on how bad its messed up.  I've had friends that have had thier computers crash shortly after after. And I've experienced it with one of my drives before.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs - Every disk is different, and everyone's backup capabilities is different, which means when you retire a faulty disk is entirely up to you.